# test connection status and speed between azure vm and client

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, slow-connection, stress-testing

We have some VMs up and running, but we are seeing slow performance on some of them. We are unsure if it is a VM problem (Azure overloaded), an intermediate network problem or a problem on the client side

Speedtest reports on the server exceeds 300Mb/s, Speedtest reports on the customers are above 10Mb/s, but as you may know speed test only verify speed between the origin an the nearest server, wich will always guarantee the best connection, is there a way to test a more real speed between the VM and the customer?

Also we want to knof if its possible to find the number of packages lost between both sides, do you know a way to find this?

Regards...

Comment: What is the workload these servers are running (IIS, SQL, SharePoint, etc.)?

Comment: windows binaries, firebird Sql, IIS, PHP, Mysql

Comment: Are the client's that experience the problem consuming http(s) endpoints only or are they also connecting directly to SQL?  Assuming it's just IIS/HTTP(s) then I would start by checking the IIS logs to see if the delays are occurring on the server or if it is a network latency issue between the server and the client.

Comment: The problem is mostly with the applications, we usually connect using rdp

Comment: I would investigate the latency (up and down speed) from the client.  You may also check the RDP settings on the client to make sure it's using the highest bandwidth setting. What is the size of your VM?